# Batch script issues when copying files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having an issue and I have been working on it for hours. I have no idea why it wont work, but I have a feeling it has to do with doing a for loop in a for loop. Its going to be a little difficult to explain. So here goes:

I have this code that works. What it does is copy 3 files from programdata to appdata. We need the "for loop" because the profile %var% is always different in that folder. It will find the name and input it to "cd" into.

```
Echo Restore Firefox Files

set copycmd=/y
timeout 7
c:
cd "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call set var1=%%j
cd profiles\%var1%
if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\places.sqlite" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\places.sqlite"
if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\key3.db" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\key3.db"
if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\signons.sqlite" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\signons.sqlite"
```

The point is, that code works. It copys from where i want it to. Here's my issue. I have this code. It will not work. Note the main loop starts where it says "Echo Loop through each user and copy files".

```
Echo Set Usernames into Variables (User1, User2, etc)
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\ProgramData\TLCloud\WindowsUsers.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set user!vidx!=%%A
    set /A i = !i! + 1
)

Echo Put Usernames into an Array
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\ProgramData\TLCloud\WindowsUsers.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set list[!i!]=%%a
)

Echo Loop Through Each User and Copy Files
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set list[') do (
    If NOT "%%s" == "Guest" (
        If NOT "%%s" == "Administrator" (

Echo Restore Firefox Files

set copycmd=/y
::start "browser" /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe
timeout 7
c:
cd "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call set var1=%%j
cd profiles\%var1%
if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\places.sqlite" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\places.sqlite"
if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\key3.db" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\key3.db"
if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\signons.sqlite" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%var1%\signons.sqlite"

)
)
)
```

Why will this code not work? Ignore the variables and array code, that is there so instead of "Username" I can eventually use "%%s" as the variable for changing usernames. But there is no reason this should not work, or am I not allowed to have a for loop in another for loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`%var1%` is replaced by an empty string already on starting processing the most outer loop with `set list[`

One solution would be using `!var1!` instead of `%var1%` as it looks like delayed environment variable expansion is already enabled. In this case `call set var1=%%j` should be also corrected to just `set var1=%%j`.

Another solution is using following code:

```
Echo Set Usernames into Variables (User1, User2, etc)
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\ProgramData\TLCloud\WindowsUsers.txt) do (
   SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
   set user!vidx!=%%A
   set /A i = !i! + 1
)

Echo Put Usernames into an Array
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\ProgramData\TLCloud\WindowsUsers.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set list[!i!]=%%a
)

Echo Loop Through Each User and Copy Files
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set list[') do (
   If NOT "%%s" == "Guest" (
      If NOT "%%s" == "Administrator" (

         Echo Restore Firefox Files

         set copycmd=/y
         rem start "browser" /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe
         rem timeout 7
         cd /D "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\"
         for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do (
            cd "profiles\%%j"
            if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%%j\places.sqlite" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%%j\places.sqlite"
            if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%%j\key3.db" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%%j\key3.db"
            if exist "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%%j\signons.sqlite" copy "C:\Programdata\TLCloud\BrowserBackup\Username\MozillaRoaming\Firefox\Profiles\%%j\signons.sqlite"
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

The `::` style commenting is a broken label. It causes `FOR` to get confused and terminate. Replace it with `REM` within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements).

Second is more major, but easily cured.

You haven't shown us your entire batch. It would follow from such statement as `set list[!i!]=%%a` that you have `delayed expansion` turned **ON**. This is excruciatingly important.

Within a block statement, any `%var%` is evaluated and replaced at **parse** time, so `%var1%` will be replaced by `var1`'s value when the entire block (ie the **outermost** `FOR` is parsed. Since you are attempting to change `var1` within your innermost loop, to access the changed value, you need to use `!var1!` which means the **current**, not the **parse-time** value of the variable.

Now, since delayed expansion appears to be enabled, simply replacing `%var1%` with `!var1!` would appear to be *a* solution. It's not hard to notice however that `var1` is being asigned the value `%%j` so there appears to be no reason to use `var1` at all - simply replace it with `%%j`!